# Hibernate query build

Tags: java, hibernate

Currently i am using the CreateSQLQuery query model to read the data from database using HIbernate. Now, I want to modify my query by using either HQL or Hibernate Criteria. My query looks like as follows.

```
select concat(d.AREA,' ',d.CITY) as location, a.TRANSFERRED_DATE as ActualTransferDate, concat(c.SCAN_CODE,',',c.SERIAL_NO) as ScanserialCode, c.MODEL_NO as ModelNum, c.ASSET_NAME as AssetName from table_transfer a, table_category b, table_asset c, table_location d where a.ASSET_ID = c.ASSET_ID and b.ASSET_CATEGORY_ID = c.ASSET_CATEGORY_ID and a.TRANSFER_TO_LOCATION=d.LOCATION_ID"
```

I am not sure how can i can convert this to Hibernate SQL or Criterion based query. Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce the fields for `location` and `scanserialCode` in your entity and mark them as @Formula

e.g.

```
@Formula("concat(d.AREA,' ',d.CITY)")
private String location;
```

See an example [here](http://www.jroller.com/eyallupu/entry/hibernate_derived_properties_performance_and) or [here](http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/formula_hibernate_annotation)

Then use join and where in HQL or Hibernate Criteria

Comment: I do not have any entity for the above query. it just return a list of pojo based mapped list which all the attributes are defined as string.

Comment: Why do you need hibernate if you don't have Entity? Create Entity for the data